# Nesting Components Livewire

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a run Table that shows this

```
ID   Name   Details  (modal button)
```

Whenever modal button is clicked, I wanted it to call another livewire component, however, I need to pass the ID of the existing table list that I have

Here is my sub component whenever the modal button is clicked.

```
public $run;

public function mount($id) 
{
    $this->run = $id;    
}

public function render()
{
    $runs = Runners_List::where('run_list_id', $this->run)->get();

    return view('livewire.runners-list', [
        'runs' => $runs,
    ]);
}
```

And in my modal, I have this

```
@livewire('runners-list', ['id' => $viewRun])
```

`$viewRun` is the ID from my main components listing or the ID per row

I need help how to pass the `$viewRun` (or ID from my main component) to the sub component above.

is this even possible? Thanks

UPDATE::

if I replace $viewRun with a value, it's able to fetch the data.

```
@livewire('runners-list', ['id' =>  $viewRun ] )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got it to work

```
<livewire:runners-list :id="$viewRun" :key="$viewRun">
```

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right path. Livewire will automatically assign parameters to matching public properties. There is no need to use mount() method at all.

Also, to keep in mind if you are using the livewire component in a loop. Similar to VueJs, if you render a component inside a loop, Livewire has no way of keeping track of which one is which. To remedy this, livewire offers a special "key" syntax.

```
@livewire('runners-list', ['run' =>  $viewRun], key($viewRun))
```

```
public $run;

public function render()
{
    return view('livewire.runners-list', [
        'runs' => Runners_List::where('run_list_id', $this->run)->get(),
    ]);
}
```

Also, I recommend not to use underscore in a class name, rather rename it to `RunnersList`